# How to determine if a parameter has been "posted" or "geted" from Java?

Tags: java, http, post, get

In ASP, there's `request.form` and `request.queryString` attributes, but in Java. It seems like we have only one collection, which can be accessed via `request.getParamaterMap`, `getParametersNames`, `getParameterValues` etc.

Is there some way to tell which values have been posted and which ones have been specified in the URL?

---

PS:

What I'm trying to achieve is to make a page that can handle the following situation

- Read the variables that came from the querystring (get)
- Read a single post with a certain name ( "xml", for example ).
- If that post is missing, read the whole body (with the
  `request.getReader()`).

I'm using tomcat 6.

According to what I've seen so far, if I issue a `request.getReader()`, posted values no longer appears in the `getParamater` collection, nevertheless querystring parameters are still there.

On the other hand, if I issue any of the `getParameters` methods, `getReader` returns empty string.

Seems like I can't have the cake and eat it too.

so, I guess the solution is the folowwing:

- Read the body with `getReader`.
- See if the xml post is there (downside, I have to manually parse the body.
- If it is, get the http message body and get rid of the "xml=" part.
- If it's not, well, just get the body.
- Read the querystring parameters through `request.getParameter`

Any better idea?

- PS: Does anybody knows how to parse the body using the same method
  used by `HttpServlet`?
- PS: [Here](http://www.aspnut.com/reference/encoding.asp) is a decoding ASP function. Shall I just rewrite it in
  Java?
- PS: Also [found](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) (don't have a machine to test it right now)

Just to clarify things. The problem seems to be that with `getParameter` you get posted values as well as values passed with the URL, consider the following example:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
  Integer i;
  String name;
  String [] values;

  for (Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {

    name = (String) e.nextElement();
    values = request.getParameterValues( name );

    for ( i=0; i < values.length; i ++ ) {
      out.println( name + ":" + values[i] + "<br/>" );
    }
  }
%>

<html>
<head><title>param test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/jsp_debug/param_test.jsp?data=from_get">
    <input type="text" name="data" value="from_post">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the output of this code is

```
data:from_get
data:from_post

...
```

Seems like in order to find which parameter came from where, I have to check `request.getQueryString`.

Comment: What server are you using? the sun HttpServer?

Comment: You should get the entire URL and deserialize the parameters. if your desired parameter is there, it's a GET. If it's not there but exists, then it's a POST param.

Answer (score 34):

[HttpServletRequest.getMethod()](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod()):

> Returns the name of the HTTP method with which this request was made, for example, GET, POST, or PUT. Same as the value of the CGI variable REQUEST_METHOD.

All you need to do is this:

```
boolean isPost = "POST".equals(request.getMethod());
```

Also I'm really confused on why you wouldn't simply use `request.getParameter("somename")` to retrieve values sent as request parameters. This method [returns the parameter regardless of whether the request was sent via a GET or a POST](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)):

> Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.

It's a heck of a lot simpler than trying to parse `getQueryString()` yourself.

Comment: If the post was made using the body of the http, instead of a parameter, I cannot get it with request.getParameter("somename"), I have to use request.getReader()... and after that I can no longer use request.getParameter

Comment: also, don't forget I can have a post with querystring info, (you just need something like 'xx.jsp?field1=value1,field2=value2' in the action parameter of the form tag), in that case, request.getMethod would return "POST", but I would have "posted" and "geted" parameters all mixed up in the getParameter collection... that's the problem...

Comment: Well I think you are using different or incorrect terminology to describe your problem then. Reading postdata or multipart data is different than reading just "parameters"

Comment: in deed I'm pretty new to java, I might confuse things a little bit... But I think that this has nothing to do with multipart stuff (I mean, the form has no enctype attribute at all)... I've updated the question to clarify things...

Comment: Or even better: `HttpMethod.GET.matches(request.getMethod())`. POST accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

No direct way.
Non-direct - check .getQueryString()

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a servlet, you can make that distinction by whether the **doGet** or **doPost** method is invoked.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException{

 //Set a variable or invoke the GET specific logic
   handleRequest(request, response);

}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException{

 //Set a variable or invoke the POST specific logic
 handleRequest(request, response);

}


public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException{

 //Do stuff with the request

}
```

Comment: you can have a post with get info, see my comment to matt b

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start with checking for query string parameters, if you see none, asume a post and then dig out the form variables?

Comment: querystrings parameters are no problem, I asume I'll allways have them around... the problem is once I issue getReader, getParamters no longer returns posted values... and I was hoping to avoid parsing the post myself...

Answer (score 1):

I did this inside my Filter so maybe someday someone can use this.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest sreq = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
    System.out.println(sreq.getMethod());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't solve your problem, but if I remember correctly, when using Struts, the ActionForm will be populated if your variables are sent in the query string or in the post body.

I found the source code for the RequestUtils class, maybe the method "populate" is what you need:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts1/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts/util/RequestUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use request.getMethod() to get any Method. I am using HandlerInterceptor for this.

check this code:

```
public class LoggingMethodInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingMethodInterceptor.class);

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    log.info("[START]  [" + request.getMethod() + "] [" + request.getRequestURL() + "] StartTime: {} milliseconds",
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    return true;
}
```